# ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443, Certification error on AWS.(ec2)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, discord.py

I had launched an EC2 with free trial (t2-micro)(WINDOWS SERVER 2019) in ap-south-2(Mumbai) . I am running a discord bot in python script. Running that script on the Mumbai server, I faced no problem.

But then due to ping issues i changed my region to us-west-1(N.California). But while running python file on California server (and any other at this point) I am having this problem with certification.

**aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]**

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I recently faced the same problem. I found my way around that by terminating all the EC2 instances. Then giving it a rest for about 1-2 hours then making a new instance.
And then by running code in that, I didn't face the problem. I don't know how it fixes the problem but I hope this helps.